# how to get sensor size for api below 21?

Tags: android

How to get sensor size of camera for API level below 21? We can use size F but it is for API level 21 and above. I have used size F in my code but it is not working for all the devices I have used the following code.

```
 private SizeF getCameraResolution(int camNum) {
    SizeF size = new SizeF(0,0);
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        String[] cameraIds = manager.getCameraIdList();
        if (cameraIds.length > camNum) {
            CameraCharacteristics character = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraIds[camNum]);
            size =character.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_PHYSICAL_SIZE);

        }
    }
    catch (CameraAccessException e)
    {
        Log.e("YourLogString", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem, you found a solution?